# OTA- /cache/recovery/uncrypt_file (Permission denied)

Tags: android-studio, update

Estoy queriendo hacer una actualizacion OTA mediante una aplicacion ubicada como platform en android 9 al intentar aplicar el update me da el siguiente error :

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cache/recovery/uncrypt_file (Permission denied)at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:308)at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:238)at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:180) at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90) at android.os.RecoverySystem.installPackage(RecoverySystem.java:562)at android.os.RecoverySystem.installPackage(RecoverySystem.java:518)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)type=1400 audit(0.0:102): avc: denied { read } for name="cache" dev="dm-0" ino=16 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:cache_file:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0
```

tengo los siguientes permisos en mi manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILESYSTEM" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM" />
```

Que permiso creen que me hace falta?

Answer (score 0):

No es un error de permisos de aplicacion es un error de permisos de acceso a persistencia

Su aplicación predeterminada está instalada en la carpeta `/system/app`. Deberías moverlo a `/system/priv-app`.

Comment: Si mi aplicación esta dentro de  `/system/priv-app.`